# From where are labels of Calls module appear in studio?

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

I tried much exploring the file/database table which is responsible for showing labels for a particular module in `studio`.

I looked at `en_Us.lang` files at all places including cache. But I don't see there a `dependency`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Core Module Labes are defined in `modules/{modulename}/language/{languagekey}.lang.php`

If you want to add or change them you should do that in the custom area you can find the Documentation for the [Language Extension Framework](http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/04_Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.5/04_Extension_Framework/Extensions/Language/):